# How to politely ask for a response?

Tags: united-states, politeness, email, professionalism

I needed to discuss some matter with one person. The outcome of that is important for me.

At the beginning of the week, I got an email where that person proposed several dates when we could have a meeting. I replied that all proposed dates suit me and I don't have a preference.

Now the week is nearly finished, the meeting should be next week, and I still haven't gotten a reply.

I'm thinking I should send an email to ask for confirmation or choose one of the proposed times and ask to confirm it.

How can I politely ask for a response, especially considering that person never replied to me when we were discussing a different case?

Comment: Hello, I see this is a reposted version of a [previous question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/18693/how-to-interpret-someone-didnt-reply-my-email) that you deleted. Since it has answers I'll leave it be, but in the future please just edit your question instead of making a new one. Thanks!

Comment: Also, this related question may be helpful: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/83/what-is-the-politest-way-to-follow-up-on-an-ignored-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shall I chose one of the proposed time and ask to confirm it.

Yes.
Your description appears to me as if the other person told you some times they are fine with. So it's your next step to pick one.

They wouldn't have told you times that don't match for them so you shouldn't waste more time discussing.

Answer (score 1):

Our lives are busy and we are often snowed by email and IM. What helps is avoiding back and forth and respecting time of our counterparts. Being empathetic will help you be a polite and efficient communicator.

Think about your goal in this example. It is not a response that you want, you want to set up an appointment. As they have already indicated available slots, simplify the life of your counterpart by sending a simple response "Perfect -- I'll put some time into our diaries! Thank you..." followed by a calendar invitation. All they will have to do is accept or reject or propose new time - just in one click!